# AppStore: how to use english only interface?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, localization, mac-app-store

The thing is that, originally my account registered in Lithuania, and thnx god we don't have translate version of appstore. Because now I moved to Netherlands, I must change country in AppStore to use my credit card. Ok I changed country, so now everything in Dutch and I don't know this language. how to switch everything to english only, and disable any other stupid locale settings on the whole OSX?? I want nothing but english.

Comment: Removing languages from the Language & Text preference pane didn't help... appleid.apple.com had a setting for a preferred language, but it didn't affect App Store or the iTunes Store on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the language of the AppStore App is always determined by the country in which your account was registered.
The AppStore app is basically just a webview which means that the localization is done by the server and not your mac, in order to change the language to english you'll have to create an english account.
You could also change the region of your account in the account settings, but that would make it impossible to use a foreign credit card.
There's also a thread on Apple's Support Communities Board about this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3797598?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What is about bilingual countries? I live in Canada, and my billing address is in Canada. I have a French version of OSx. I changed preferred language to English, but the interface of AppStore (the part, which is on the web) is still in French.